# javascript popups

Tags: javascript, ajax, animation

Is there a good library which has nice animated popups? I'm looking for a popup where I could have basic html fields like text area and stuff....

I'm looking for a popup which will overlay on the current page..not the popup which would open a new re-sized window.

Comment: -1 No prior research shown. Please bring an initial-offering to the table, such as one or two researched solutions and what they have or lack in relationship to requirements. It increases the quality of questions and answers. (I have searched g***** in the past for this particular request and found no shortage of either leads or information.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few User Interface Libraries for JavaScript out there, the most famous one is probably [**jQuery UI**](http://jqueryui.com/). You can customize jQuery UI with  CSS via so-called Skins and there is a huge set of widgets. You might want to take a look at jQuery UI's [dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

Answer (score 0):

These are called modal dialogs or lightboxes. I've used [nyromodal](http://nyromodal.nyrodev.com/) before and it's one of the most flexible.

If you're looking for easy-to-add eyecandy, [jQuery Tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay/index.html) usually has some great options here, for example, [this demo](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/apple.html).